# Why do threads containing a MPSC channel never join?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've this example collected from the internet:

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

// Transaction enum
enum Transaction {
    Widthdrawl(String, f64),
    Deposit(String, f64),
}

fn main() {
    //A banking send receive example...
    // set the number of customers
    let n_customers = 10;

    // Create a "customer" and a "banker"
    let (customers, banker) = mpsc::channel();

    let handles = (0..n_customers + 1)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|i| {
            // Create another "customer"
            let customer = customers.clone();

            // Create the customer thread
            let handle = thread::Builder::new()
                .name(format!("{}{}", "thread", i).into())
                .spawn(move || {
                    // Define Transaction
                    let trans_type = match i % 2 {
                        0 => Transaction::Deposit(
                            thread::current().name().unwrap().to_string(),
                            (i + 5) as f64 * 10.0,
                        ),
                        _ => Transaction::Widthdrawl(
                            thread::current().name().unwrap().to_string(),
                            (i + 10) as f64 * 5.0,
                        ),
                    };

                    // Send the Transaction
                    customer.send(trans_type).unwrap();
                });

            handle
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Result<thread::JoinHandle<_>, _>>>();

    // Wait for threads to finish
    for handle in handles {
        handle.unwrap().join().unwrap()
    }

    // Create a bank thread
    let bank = thread::spawn(move || {
        // Create a value
        let mut balance: f64 = 10000.0;
        println!("Initially, Bank value: {}", balance);

        // Perform the transactions in order
        //banker.recv_timeout(Duration::new(5, 0)); <-- TIMEOUT line...

        banker.into_iter().for_each(|i| {
            let mut customer_name: String = "None".to_string();
            match i {
                // Subtract for Widthdrawls
                Transaction::Widthdrawl(cust, amount) => {
                    customer_name = cust;
                    println!(
                        "Customer name {} doing withdrawal of amount {}",
                        customer_name, amount
                    );
                    balance = balance - amount;
                }
                // Add for deposits
                Transaction::Deposit(cust, amount) => {
                    customer_name = cust;
                    println!(
                        "Customer name  {} doing deposit of amount {}",
                        customer_name, amount
                    );
                    balance = balance + amount;
                }
            }

            println!("Customer is {}, Bank value: {}", customer_name, balance);
        });
    });

    // Let the bank finish
    bank.join().unwrap(); //THE THREAD DOES NOT END!!
}
```

The `bank` thread never joins, thus not ending the main.

If I remove the `join` and uncomment the timeout line above, the bank thread sometimes does not wait for the customer threads send (which, I think is ok).

```
//banker.recv_timeout(Duration::new(5, 0)); <-- TIMEOUT line...
```

What could be the reason for the bank thread not joining or what could be a better way to make it understand that no more customer messages will be coming? (as I think the `timeout()` may not be a reliable way in here).

Comment: Re, "what could be a better way to make it understand that no more customer messages will be coming?" Learning Rust still is on my to-do list, So I don't know exactly what your thread is doing, but...  If it's processing a _blocking queue_, then my favorite way to deal with that problem is the _poison pill_ solution. The poison pill is a unique, dummy object of the same type that the queue normally holds. When a thread that is consuming items from the queue gets the poison pill object, it cleans up whatever needs to be cleaned up, and then it self-terminates.

Comment: ...P.S., Don't forget: The thread that is requesting to shut down the queue must enqueue at least as many copies of the poison pill as there are consumer threads taking items from the queue.

Comment: Also: Your main thread appears to join the one-and-only "banker" thread immediately after creating it. What's the point of that? Why not just do the "banker" stuff _in_ the main thread?

Comment: @Solomon Slow Thanks for your comments. I know about those solutions. But this Rust code does not involve queues, rather mpsc channels for message passing. Thanks

Comment: Re, "...mspc channels..," I'm pretty sure that [mspc channels](https://blog.softwaremill.com/multithreading-in-rust-with-mpsc-multi-producer-single-consumer-channels-db0fc91ae3fa) is a specific implementation of  [blocking queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue). If a "producer" thread can put things in to an mspc channel, and the consumer thread takes them out in the same order that they went in, then the poison pill approach should work just fine.  You'll have to be careful though to shut down all of the prodcers _before_ inserting the poison pill.

Comment: That could be a possibility for sure. I'll check. And thanks again. Regards.

Comment: Adding a drop(sender) solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I need to drop the `tx` channel after all producers are done and then the consumer stops after that:

```
// Wait for threads to finish
for handle in handles {
    handle.unwrap().join().unwrap()
}

drop(customers);

// Create a bank thread
```